# CodeignitEr Session not working with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

The issue here is I am trying to login into my system via ajax. Let me explain it to your first.

when my user puts in his login details it will be send to the server via Ajax request and then once it gets verified i create an entry into a session and save the information like userid and logged_in flag.

And then i return those value through Json back to user which is processed by a piece of javascript and redirect the user to dashboard.

If the user is not authenticated it shows an error.

But now whats happening here is. When i create a session variable and when the user is redirected to the dashboard. Sometimes it does not create the session variables and thats why i cant show logout button?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve used AJAX-heavy web apps built on a CI backend, you might have noticed premature session expiration, even if you’re expiration was set to never expire ($config['sess_expiration'] = 0; in application/config/config.php)

This was apparently due to AJAX requests not regenerating sessions, and apparent collisions. Long story short, last month there was a patch introduced without much fanfare, which (so far) seems to be working for me.

Replace your system/libraries/Session.php file with the one found here (CI’s git):

https://raw.github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php