# codeigniter 3 ajax not preserve SESSION

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to make a REST API using ajax codeigniter 3 but not preserve session vars when I make requests from the client..
and need session of files "$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';"
and i try many resources even extends the session class and did not work, also change the parameters config "sess_driver","sess_expiration","sess_expiration","sess_save_path","sess_time_to_update" and not, what alternatives can be used for use with Ajax and sessiones to be preserved

```php
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH .  "/session_data";
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;//try with 0 and 7200 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008452/codeigniter-session-not-working-with-ajax?rq=1
```

my controller login

```php
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
if(isset($is_logged_in) ||  $is_logged_in == true){
    echo "the session is ready"; 
else{
    echo "the session is loading"; 
    $this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', $output['token']);     
}
```

always show "the session is loading"

and my client

```
$http.get( $rootScope.$APIURL + "users/login", null)
.success(function(data) {
    defered.resolve(data);
}).error(function(err) {
    defered.reject(err)
});
return defered.promise;
```

and i load the session library in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation','session');
```

thank you very much for the answers I have tried everything and not to use alternatives

Comment: `$config['sess_save_path']` MUST be a valid path. This is where the session files are stored

Comment: 'i change $config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH .  "/session_data"; and not working

Comment: Can you confirm that files are being saved to that location?

Comment: yes i confirm and create the files and this folder have permisions this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/ZUqfype.png

Comment: `$output['token'] === TRUE` at this point `$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in', $output['token']);` ?

Comment: yess i have two links: one for log in [http://api.gestionalo.co/users/login](http://api.gestionalo.co/users/login) and for logout  [http://api.gestionalo.co/users/logout](http://api.gestionalo.co/users/logout) this work perfectly int the broswer but ajax not working

Comment: Keeping the same protocol (http / https)?  Using any hooks?

Comment: yess i the rootScope.$APIURL = "http://api.gestionalo.co/";

Comment: I worked with CI a while back a common problem I used to have is when the session regenerates through the Ajax request the session ID changes but your cookie does not get updated. So when the next requests are sent they use the old session ID and the data is not there anymore. You can create a replacement session library to detect if its an AJAX request and don't regenerate. Or if you want to allow it to regenerate, send it back in the response and update the session cookie with the JS (doesn't always work because JS can send multiple Ajax requests). Hopefully this will help :)