# CodeIgniter is not saving session trough AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem that I hope you can help me. I have a method in my controller which create a CodeIgniter session. For make sure that is creating correct I do a `print_r()` function, after create the session. Then, in my Ajax request I put a `location.reload` for refresh the page.

This what I have in my method:

```
public function CreateSession() {
   $response = $this->mymodel->registerUser();
   //The response in this case of the method registerUser() is an array such as:
   /*
   Array
    (
       [id_web_user] => 982
       [nombre_web_user] => name
       [apellidos_web_user] => lastname
       [user_mail] => asf21@gmail.com
       [user_password] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
       [id_pais] => 1
       [profile_picture] => n/a
       [id_seccion_registro] => 1
       [id_estatus] => 0
       [id_usuario_alta] => 1
       [id_usuario_mod] => 1
       [fecha_ultimo_ingreso] => 2018-03-25 01:43:17
       [fecha_alta] => 2018-03-25 01:43:17
       [fecha_modificacion] => 2018-03-25 01:43:17
    )
    */

    //Then when I get the response array, I create a new array which contains an specific data for store in a session within userdata like:

    $newdata = array(
        'id_web_user' => $response['id_web_user'],
        'nombre_web_user' => $response['nombre_web_user'],
        'apellidos_web_user' => $response['apellidos_web_user'],
        'user_mail' => $response['user_mail'],
        'profile_picture' => $response['profile_picture']
    );

    //Finally I create the session:
    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

    //And then, wheter I do a print_r($this->session->userdata) for verify that the session was created successfully, I get something like:
    /*
    Array
    (
       [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521938249
       [id_web_user] => 983
       [nombre_web_user] => name
       [apellidos_web_user] => lastname
       [user_mail] => asf21@gmail.com
       [profile_picture] => n/a
    )
    */

   //In this step I do an echo 1; because my Ajax request is waiting for that and make a "location.reload()", so:
   echo 1;
}
```

This method is called trough Ajax, like;

```
//base_url was defined previously
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : base_url + "/mycontroller/CreateSession",
   data : {},
   success : function(response) {
      if ( response == 1 ) {
        location.reload();
     }
   }
});
```

So, finally, in the Ajax request I do `location.reload` but when the page refresh this is redirecting me to `http://localhost/` and also when I want to check what contains `$this->session->userdata` with `print_r($this->session->userdata);` this is empty.

What I'm doing wrong? I was trying to find a solution and some people are saying that the Session.php of CI has a bug and need replace for a new which exists in CI's Github. Other people say that it's problem of the cookies because when the session contains more than 4KB this errased automatically. This is driving mad, I hope you can help me.  Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Have you set the session save path on config.php Do not leave it null.

Comment: you are using ci 2 right?

Comment: After all enabling session.autostart with 1 the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Did you call this library $this->load->library('session');

Or call this library in application/config/autoload. php file using... $autoload["libraries"] = array("session" ) ;

Comment: Yep, I'm already put in my controller $this->load->library('session'); and in my autoload.php $autoload["libraries"] = array("session" ) ;

Comment: If you put in autoload then its not neded to call in controller. If it included like this it will call twice

Comment: in any case that wouldn't cause an issue like this. ci already has mechanisms in place to prevent loading the same class twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I solve my problem but with some limitations. Seems that CodeIgniter cannot store a lot of data within an array in the session, so I took the example for create sessions which exists in the official documentation.

I took the example from: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

```
    $newdata = array(
            'username'  => 'johndoe',
            'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
            'logged_in' => TRUE
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

So, with the above code example I based for build a new custom session. Then, I modify the part of my code which before was:

```
$newdata = array(
    'id_web_user' => $response['id_web_user'],
    'nombre_web_user' => $response['nombre_web_user'],
    'apellidos_web_user' => $response['apellidos_web_user'],
    'user_mail' => $response['user_mail'],
    'profile_picture' => $response['profile_picture']
);

//Finally I create the session:
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

For

```
   $id = $response['id_web_user'];
   $username = htmlspecialchars(sprintf('%s %s', $response['nombre_web_user'], $response['apellidos_web_user']));
   $newdata = array(
        'username'  => $username,
        'id_web_user' => $id,
        'logged_in' => TRUE
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Please take a look that based in my last code I only took three values from my `$response` array for build my custom session, they are:

```
$response['id_web_user']
$response['nombre_web_user']
$response['apellidos_web_user']
```

So, I took only that tree values and for save them separately in their respective variables, which are now:

```
$id = $response['id_web_user'];
$username = htmlspecialchars(sprintf('%s %s', $response['nombre_web_user'], $response['apellidos_web_user']));
```

Please take a look that I add (as the CodeIgniter example) a third value within my array which is `'logged_in' => TRUE`.

And this worked for me.

Conclusions: I have to say that find a solution on internet never works for me. The first thing that I did was search on google why calling a method which create a session trough AJAX was not working and I found two possibilities:

1. Seems that CodeIgniter had a bug since 2014 when the sessions was creating trough AJAX and for a possible solution you needed to replace the Session.php file into the folder `system/Sessions.php`. This solution never worked for me because the file that the person suggested in both references doesn't matched with my CodeIgniter files.

Reference pages:

[CodeignitEr Session not working with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008452/codeigniter-session-not-working-with-ajax)

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68010.html

2. By default CodeIgniter stores the session data in a cookie, which has an upper limit of 2KB-4KB in size depending on browser. If you are trying to store more than 4KB of data in the session you will start running into issues. And I think probably this is was exactly that I was doing all this time, storing a lot of data that was upon 4KB.

Reference pages:

[codeIgniter : losing session data after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122848/codeigniter-losing-session-data-after-login)

I hope that my answer will enough for let me tell you what and how this solve my issue. If something is missing in this answer, tell me for update it. Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate on how this has fixed your issue? you have 5 array elements before and only 3 now - that isn't that much of a data difference (infact it's negligible). `logged_in` doesn't really do anything special with ci btw.

Comment: Yes, no problem. For that can I edit this answer or do I create a new answer?

Comment: just edit this one. but what you are saying, is that by reducing the array size your session is now working? that is very very odd behavior as your array isn't that large to begin with

Comment: First off I'd like to say you obviously did a lot of research which is awesome and that I'm purely looking at this from a troubleshooting standpoint. The codeigniter session bug was an issue with ci2 and was eliminated when the session library was completely rewritten. The second thing you mentioned was the size - this could very well be a possibility as I don't know how long your array values were originally. From a debugging standpoint I would *revert* to your original code, and instead, use db based sessions. All it requires is a new db table and changing a variable in config.

Comment: If your problem is resolved using your original code and db sessions then we know it was a cookie size issue and no further action is needed. After reverting to original code, before changing to a db sessions, check to see if this issue is in other browsers like firefox as well. Otherwise, I think this might be something worth reporting to the CI devs.

Comment: Yes. Version 3.1.8